# Phonegap - multiple CSS/JS files or one mega flle

Tags: cordova

When creating a web page (or a web app) it is common practice to attempt to reduce the number of external resources that need to be fetched by combining multiple CSS/JS files into a single one whenever possible.

In a well written hybrid Phonegap app the script and style resources will be local to the app - typically in the app/www/js|css folders.  My assumption:there is no real overhead involved in using separate files - since they are all locally available anyway - as opposed to one single file.

However, I am wondering - in the interests of optimizing the way the app works and uses device resources are there any reasons why one would attempt to merge multiple script/style files into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there will be no significant difference in performance. While loading all the assets at once will be a little bit faster.

But if you are going to publish you app into the App/Play Store then you will probably want to obfuscate and minify your source files. So your competitors don't have an access to the code. And typically minification/obfuscation involves combining all the files into one.